# C base64 encode string

Tags: c

Folks,
  Trying to troubleshoot an issue with the base64 function below.  About 2-3% of the requests that pass through this process return an incorrect (too short) base64output.

```
static const char *header_request_gce(request_rec *r, char *a)
    {
    char *tim = apr_palloc(r->pool, APR_RFC822_DATE_LEN);
    apr_rfc822_date(tim, r->request_time);

    char *uri = apr_psprintf(r->pool, "%s", r->uri);

    char encode[32768];
    //encode = malloc(strlen(tim)+strlen(uri)); /* make space for the new string (should check the return value ...) */
    strcpy(encode, "GET\n\n\n");
    strcat(encode, tim);
    strcat(encode, "\n");
    strcat(encode, uri);

    unsigned int encode_length = strlen(encode);

    unsigned char* result;
    unsigned char* key = (unsigned char*) "2kcXHh+K+XLtI61/KIV3d1tVzOooTdeOqFii9osz";

    static char res_hexstring[8192];

    result = HMAC(EVP_sha1(), key, 40, encode, encode_length, NULL, NULL);

    char *base64(const unsigned char *input, int length);
    char *base64output = base64(result, strlen(result));

    return base64output;
    }


char *base64(const unsigned char *input, int length)
{
    BIO *bmem, *b64;
    BUF_MEM *bptr;

    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bmem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    b64 = BIO_push(b64, bmem);
    BIO_write(b64, input, length);
    BIO_flush(b64);
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(b64, &bptr);

    char *buff = (char *)malloc(bptr->length);
    memcpy(buff, bptr->data, bptr->length-1);
    buff[bptr->length-1] = 0;

    BIO_free_all(b64);

    return buff;
}
```

The key above has been modified ofcourse, but kept in the correct character format

Comment: Give examples that fail, please, and show a hex dump of the output.

Comment: It's not only in the 2-3% of the cases that it generates a too short string. If `bptr->length` is what I think it is, then this code always cuts off the last character.

Comment: bad response:ZLtXucRTj60=

Comment: good response: X6OkpaJRdTyLhNmy+h2PX5uJRiU=

Comment: another bad response: /i5ayn0=

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
char *base64output = base64(result, strlen(result));
```

The data (output from sha1) that you are encoding can contain the `NUL` byte which means strlen returns a number that is too small (with a probability of `1 - (255/256)^20` which is approximately `7.5%`). Rather than call `strlen` you should just pass in the size as a constant. I believe that if you are just encoding a sha1 hash, the length will always be 20:

```
char *base64output = base64(result, 20);
```

There is probably a better way to get that length from an HMAC function or something (so that it updates automatically if you change the hashing algorithm), but I am, admittedly, not very familiar with the hashing functions you're using.